# c# ASP.NET MVC What is the HTML definitions for HtmlHelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper

Can anybody tell me what is the HTML 'translation' for this HTML Helper?

```
@Html.DropDownList("Type_Id", new SelectList(listaRoles, "Role_Name"))<br />
```

Do you now any website or reference where I can find the HTML definitions for any others HTML Helpers?

Comment: Run it and find out? This creates a `<select id="Type_Id" name="Type_Id">` with options based on the `listaRoles` collection. Most of the HTML helpers are fairly self-explanatory, but [here's once reference](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/N50P050314-Understanding-HTML-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html) with a few examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good reference for html http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers

- Action
- ActionLink
- Url content
- RenderAction
- RenderPartial